# Why CriteriaQuery is putting dot in hibernate string?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with my multiselect. I'm using it as an Specification with multiple joins. I don't know why hibernate decides to put a dot in the query. the error is shown below in the query. this is the constructor I'm using

```
public HelperOutput(Long id,
                        String personName,
                        Long helperTypeId,
                        String helperTypeTitle,
                        String agencyTitle,
                        String regionalOfficeTitle,
                        String basketPartTitle,
                        YesNo allowedToOperate,
                        YesNo hasFlatTirePack,
                        Long fleetRescueId,
                        Long cityId,
                        String cityName,
                        Long skillLevel,
                        String helperRankTitle,
                        Long personId,
                        Long helperRate,
                        String personelId,
                        Long regionalOfficeId,
                        Long basketPartId,
                        String mobile,
                        String fleetName,
                        ExpertType expertType,
                        Long maxConcurrentWork,
                        Set<Long> dutyCityIds
                        ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.helperTypeId = helperTypeId;
        this.helperTypeTitle = helperTypeTitle;
        this.agencyTitle = agencyTitle;
        this.regionalOfficeId = regionalOfficeId;
        this.regionalOfficeTitle = regionalOfficeTitle;
        this.basketPartTitle = basketPartTitle;
        this.fleetRescueId = fleetRescueId;
        this.cityId = cityId;
        this.helperRankTitle = helperRankTitle;
        this.personId = personId;
        this.basketPartId = basketPartId;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.fleetName = fleetName;
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.personName = personName;
        this.allowedToOperate = allowedToOperate;
        this.hasFlatTirePack = hasFlatTirePack;
        this.skillLevel = skillLevel;
        this.helperRate = helperRate;
        this.personelId = personelId;
        this.expertType = expertType;
        this.maxConcurrentWork = maxConcurrentWork;
        this.dutyCityIds = dutyCityIds;
    }
```

this is the multiselect which is similar to the constructor.

```
cq.multiselect(root.get(Helper_.ID),
                    personName,
                    helperHelperTypeJoin.get(HelperType_.ID),
                    helperHelperTypeJoin.get(HelperType_.TITLE),
                    helperAgencyJoin.get(Agency_.TITLE),
                    helperRegionalOfficeJoin.get(RegionalOffice_.TITLE)
                    , helperBasketPartJoin.get(Basket_.TITLE),
                    root.get(Helper_.ALLOWED_TO_OPERATE),
                    root.get(Helper_.HAS_FLAT_TIRE_PACK),
                    fleetRescueJoin.get(HelperFleet_.ID),
                    helperCityJoin.get(City_.ID) ,
                    helperCityJoin.get(City_.NAME),
                    root.get(Helper_.SKILL_LEVEL),
                    helperRankJoin.get(HelperRank_.NAME),
                    helperPersonJoin.get(Person_.ID),
                    root.get(Helper_.helperRate),
                    root.get(Helper_.personelId),
                    helperRegionalOfficeJoin.get(RegionalOffice_.ID),
                    helperBasketPartJoin.get(Basket_.ID),
                    helperPersonJoin.get(Person_.MOBILE),
                    HelperFleetJoin.get(Fleet_.NAME),
                    root.get(Helper_.EXPERT_TYPE),
                    root.get(Helper_.MAX_CONCURRENT_WORK),
                    root.get(Helper_.DUTY_CITIES)
            );
```

this is the hibernate **query** which I don't know why it has a dot.

```
select
        * 
    from
        ( select
            helper0_.ID as col_0_0_,
            person3_.NAME as col_1_0_,
            helpertype7_.ID as col_2_0_,
            helpertype7_.TITLE as col_3_0_,
            agency2_.TITLE as col_4_0_,
            regionalof8_.TITLE as col_5_0_,
            basket6_.TITLE as col_6_0_,
            helper0_.ALLOWED_TO_OPERATE as col_7_0_,
            helper0_.HAS_FLAT_TIRE_PACK as col_8_0_,
            helperflee4_.ID as col_9_0_,
            city1_.ID as col_10_0_,
            city1_.NAME as col_11_0_,
            helper0_.SKILL_LEVEL as col_12_0_,
            helperrank9_.NAME as col_13_0_,
            person3_.ID as col_14_0_,
            helper0_.HELPER_RATE as col_15_0_,
            helper0_.PERSONELID as col_16_0_,
            regionalof8_.ID as col_17_0_,
            basket6_.ID as col_18_0_,
            person3_.MOBILE as col_19_0_,
            fleet5_.NAME as col_20_0_,
            helper0_.EXPERT_TYPE as col_21_0_,
            helper0_.MAX_CONCURRENT_WORK as col_22_0_,
            . as col_23_0_    <----------- this causes the problem
        from
            OPR.TBL_HELPER helper0_ 
        left outer join
            OPR.TBL_CITY city1_ 
                on helper0_.CITY_ID=city1_.ID 
        left outer join
            TBL_AGENCY agency2_ 
                on helper0_.AGENCY_ID=agency2_.ID 
        left outer join
            OPR.TBL_PERSONS person3_ 
                on helper0_.PERSON_ID=person3_.ID 
        left outer join
            OPR.TBL_HELPER_FLEET helperflee4_ 
                on helper0_.HELPER_FLEET_ID=helperflee4_.ID 
        left outer join
            OPR.NOEKHODROEMDAD fleet5_ 
                on helperflee4_.NOEKHODROEMDAD_ID=fleet5_.NOEKHODROEMDADID 
        left outer join
            OPR.TBL_BASKET basket6_ 
                on helper0_.BASKET_PART_ID=basket6_.ID 
        left outer join
            OPR.TBL_HELPER_TYPE helpertype7_ 
                on helper0_.HELPER_TYPE_ID=helpertype7_.ID 
        left outer join
            TBL_REGIONAL_OFFICE regionalof8_ 
                on helper0_.REGIONAL_OFFICE_ID=regionalof8_.ID 
        left outer join
            OPR.TBL_HELPER_RANK helperrank9_ 
                on helper0_.RANK_HELPER_ID=helperrank9_.ID 
        left outer join
            TBL_HELPER_DUTY_CITIES dutycities10_ 
                on helper0_.ID=dutycities10_.DUTY_CITY_ID 
        left outer join
            OPR.TBL_CITY city11_ 
                on dutycities10_.ESTABLISHMENT_CITY_ID=city11_.ID 
        inner join
            TBL_HELPER_DUTY_CITIES dutycities12_ 
                on helper0_.ID=dutycities12_.DUTY_CITY_ID 
        where
            1=1 
            and 1=1 
        order by
            helper0_.ALLOWED_TO_OPERATE asc,
            person3_.NAME asc ) 
    where
        rownum <= ?
```

and at last I get this error when returning an Specification from the predicates I made.
Error:

```
2022-01-31 15:40:08.419 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00936: missing expression
 
2022-01-31 15:40:08.444 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] ERROR com.eki.opr.config.LoggingAspect - ----> @AfterThrowing method: GenericRepository.findAll(..) 
2022-01-31 15:40:08.445 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] ERROR com.eki.opr.config.LoggingAspect - ----> detailedMessage: ORA-00936: missing expression
 
2022-01-31 15:40:08.445 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] ERROR com.eki.opr.config.LoggingAspect - ----> detailedCause: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet 
2022-01-31 15:40:08.445 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] ERROR com.eki.opr.config.LoggingAspect - ----> @AfterThrowing method: HelperServiceImpl.findByCriteria(..) 
2022-01-31 15:40:08.445 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] ERROR com.eki.opr.config.LoggingAspect - ----> detailedMessage: ORA-00936: missing expression
 
2022-01-31 15:40:08.445 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] ERROR com.eki.opr.config.LoggingAspect - ----> detailedCause: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet 
2022-01-31 15:40:08.446 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] ERROR com.eki.opr.config.LoggingAspect - ----> @AfterThrowing method: HelperController.show(..) 
2022-01-31 15:40:08.446 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] ERROR com.eki.opr.config.LoggingAspect - ----> detailedMessage: ORA-00936: missing expression
 
2022-01-31 15:40:08.446 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] ERROR com.eki.opr.config.LoggingAspect - ----> detailedCause: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

**EDIT**
these are the entities:

```
@Entity(name = "HELPER")
@Table(name = "TBL_HELPER", schema = "OPR")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"person", "agency", "helperType", "regionalOffice", "basket_part", "helperRank"})
@ToString(exclude = {"person", "agency", "helperType", "regionalOffice", "basket_part", "helperRank"})
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Helper implements Serializable {


    private Long id;
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "assigned-sequence",
            strategy = "com.eki.opr.utils.StringSequenceIdentifier"
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            generator = "assigned-sequence",
            strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String largeId;

    private Long skillLevel;
    private Long currentWorkCount;
    private Long maxConcurrentWork;
    private YesNo allowedToOperate;
    private YesNo hasGps;
    private YesNo isAutoDialer;
    private YesNo isPartSupply;
    private YesNo hasFlatTirePack;
    private String imei;
    private String address;
    private String personelId;
    private String reservedMobile;


    private Person person;
    private HelperFleet helperFleet;
    private HelperType helperType;
    private RegionalOffice regionalOffice;
    private Agency agency;
    private Basket basket_part;
    private Basket basket_tools;
    private YesNo hasPos;
    private String posSerial;
    private HelperRank helperRank;

    private Parameter contractType;

    private Set<ServiceType> serviceTypes = new HashSet<ServiceType>();

    private Long helperRate;


    private ExpertType expertType = ExpertType.HELPER;

    public Helper() {

    }

    private City city;

    @JoinColumn(name = "CITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }


    
    private Set<HelperDutyCity> dutyCities = new HashSet<>();
    
    /* in this part mappedBy's value should be changed to helper because the 
     join must be on helper not dutyCityId*/

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = HelperDutyCity.class, mappedBy = "dutyCityId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<HelperDutyCity> getDutyCities() {
        return dutyCities;
    }

    public void setDutyCities(Set<HelperDutyCity> dutyCities) {
        this.dutyCities = dutyCities;
    }

    public void setHelperRate(Long helperRate) {
        this.helperRate = helperRate;
    }
    @Column(name = "HELPER_RATE")
    public Long getHelperRate() {
        return helperRate;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_helper")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_helper", sequenceName = "SA.SEQ_EMDADGAR_ID", allocationSize = 1,initialValue = 63442)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    @Column(name = "SKILL_LEVEL")
    public Long getSkillLevel() {
        return skillLevel;
    }

    public void setSkillLevel(Long skillLevel) {
        this.skillLevel = skillLevel;
    }


    @Column(name = "MAX_CONCURRENT_WORK")
    public Long getMaxConcurrentWork() {
        return maxConcurrentWork;
    }

    public void setMaxConcurrentWork(Long maxConcurrentWork) {
        this.maxConcurrentWork = maxConcurrentWork;
    }


    @Column(name = "CURRENT_WORK_COUNT")
    public Long getCurrentWorkCount() {
        return currentWorkCount;
    }

    public void setCurrentWorkCount(Long currentWorkCount) {
        this.currentWorkCount = currentWorkCount;
    }


    @Column(name = "ALLOWED_TO_OPERATE")
    @Convert(converter = YesNoConverter.class)
    public YesNo getAllowedToOperate() {
        return allowedToOperate;
    }

    public void setAllowedToOperate(YesNo allowedToOperate) {
        this.allowedToOperate = allowedToOperate;
    }


    @Column(name = "HAS_GPS")
    @Convert(converter = YesNoConverter.class)
    public YesNo getHasGps() {
        return hasGps;
    }

    public void setHasGps(YesNo hasGps) {
        this.hasGps = hasGps;
    }


    @Column(name = "PART_SUPPLY")
    @Convert(converter = YesNoConverter.class)
    public YesNo getIsPartSupply() {
        return isPartSupply;
    }

    public void setIsPartSupply(YesNo isPartSupply) {
        this.isPartSupply = isPartSupply;
    }


    @Column(name = "PERSONELID")
    public String getPersonelId() {
        return personelId;
    }

    public void setPersonelId(String personelId) {
        this.personelId = personelId;
    }


    @Column(name = "HAS_FLAT_TIRE_PACK")
    @Convert(converter = YesNoConverter.class)
    public YesNo getHasFlatTirePack() {
        return hasFlatTirePack;
    }

    public void setHasFlatTirePack(YesNo hasFlatTirePack) {
        this.hasFlatTirePack = hasFlatTirePack;
    }


    @Column(name = "IMEI")
    public String getImei() {
        return imei;
    }

    public void setImei(String imei) {
        this.imei = imei;
    }
    @JoinColumn(name = "CREATED_BY", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private PersonUnion createdBy;
    @Column(name = "CREATED_AT")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "IS_AUTO_DIALER")
    @Convert(converter = YesNoConverter.class)
    public YesNo getIsAutoDialer() {
        return isAutoDialer;
    }

    public void setIsAutoDialer(YesNo isAutoDialer) {
        this.isAutoDialer = isAutoDialer;
    }


    @Column(name = "RESERVED_MOBILE")
    public String getReservedMobile() {
        return reservedMobile;
    }

    @Column(name = "HAS_POS")
    @Convert(converter = YesNoConverter.class)
    public YesNo getHasPos() { return hasPos; }
    public void setHasPos(YesNo hasPos) {
        this.hasPos = hasPos;
    }

    @Column(name = "POS_SERIAL")
    public String getPosSerial() { return posSerial; }
    public void setPosSerial(String posSerial) {
        this.posSerial = posSerial;
    }

    public void setReservedMobile(String reservedMobile) {
        this.reservedMobile = reservedMobile;
    }
    @JoinColumn(name = "MODIFIED_BY", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private PersonUnion modifiedBy;
    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_AT")
    private LocalDateTime modifiedAt;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "HELPER_TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public HelperType getHelperType() {
        return helperType;
    }

    public void setHelperType(HelperType helperType) {
        this.helperType = helperType;
    }


    @JoinColumn(name = "REGIONAL_OFFICE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public RegionalOffice getRegionalOffice() {
        return regionalOffice;
    }

    public void setRegionalOffice(RegionalOffice regionalOffice) {
        this.regionalOffice = regionalOffice;
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "AGENCY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Agency getAgency() {
        return agency;
    }

    public void setAgency(Agency agency) {
        this.agency = agency;
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "BASKET_PART_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Basket getBasket_part() {
        return basket_part;
    }

    public void setBasket_part(Basket basket_part) {
        this.basket_part = basket_part;
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "BASKET_TOOLS_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Basket getBasket_tools() {
        return basket_tools;
    }

    public void setBasket_tools(Basket basket_tools) {
        this.basket_tools = basket_tools;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "HELPER_FLEET_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    public HelperFleet getHelperFleet() {
        return helperFleet;
    }

    public void setHelperFleet(HelperFleet helperFleet) {
        this.helperFleet = helperFleet;
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "RANK_HELPER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public HelperRank getHelperRank() {
        return helperRank;
    }

    public void setHelperRank(HelperRank helperRank) {
        this.helperRank = helperRank;
    }


    @Column(name = "LARGE_ID")
    public String getLargeId(){return this.largeId;}

    public void setLargeId(String largeId){this.largeId = largeId;}

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "TBL_HELPER_SERVICE_TYPE", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"HELPER_ID", "SERVICE_TYPE_ID"})},
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "HELPER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SERVICE_TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    public Set<ServiceType> getServiceTypes() {
        return serviceTypes;
    }

    public void setServiceTypes(Set<ServiceType> serviceTypes) {
        this.serviceTypes = serviceTypes;
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTRACT_TYPE")
    @ManyToOne
    public Parameter getContractType() {
        return contractType;
    }

    public void setContractType(Parameter contractType){
        this.contractType = contractType;
    }

    @Convert(converter = ExpertTypeConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "EXPERT_TYPE")
    public ExpertType getExpertType() {
        return expertType;
    }

    public void setExpertType(ExpertType expertType) {
        this.expertType = expertType;
    }

    public void fromDto(HelperInput input) {
        this.id = input.getId();
        this.address = input.getAddress();
        this.allowedToOperate = input.getAllowedToOperate();
        this.currentWorkCount = input.getCurrentWorkCount();
        this.hasGps = input.getHasGps();
        this.hasFlatTirePack = input.getHasFlatTirePack();
        this.isAutoDialer = input.getIsAutoDialer();
        this.personelId = input.getPersonelId();
        this.isPartSupply = input.getIsPartSupply();
        this.maxConcurrentWork = input.getMaxConcurrentWork();
        this.hasPos = input.getHasPos();
        this.posSerial = input.getPosSerial();
        this.skillLevel = input.getSkillLevel();
        this.reservedMobile = input.getReservedMobile();

        if (input.getId() == null) { //first time
            this.largeId = StringSequenceIdentifier.generateLargeId();
            this.createdBy = input.getCreatedByEntity();
            this.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
            this.modifiedBy = input.getCreatedByEntity();
            this.modifiedAt = createdAt;
        } else {
            this.modifiedBy = input.getModifiedByEntity();
            this.modifiedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
        }

        this.helperRate = input.getHelperRate();

    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize
@Table(name = "TBL_HELPER_DUTY_CITIES")
@IdClass(HelperDutyCityKey.class)
public class HelperDutyCity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "HELPER_ID")
    private Helper helper;

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ESTABLISHMENT_CITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private City establishmentCityId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DUTY_CITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private City dutyCityId;


    public HelperDutyCity(Helper helper, City establishmentCityId) {
        this.helper = helper;
        this.establishmentCityId = establishmentCityId;
    }

}
```

```
@Data
@ToString(exclude = {"regions","regionalOffice", "province","productCities"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"regions","regionalOffice", "province","productCities"})
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_CITY", schema = "OPR")
public class City implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "seqCity",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "SEQ_CITY"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "100219"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
            }
    )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqCity")
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch =  FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROVINCE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Province province;

    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "assigned-sequence",
            strategy = "com.eki.opr.utils.StringSequenceIdentifier"
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            generator = "assigned-sequence",
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "LARGE_ID")
    private String largeId;

    @Column(name = "OPR_SHAHR_ID")
    private Double oprCityId;

    @Column(name = "LATITUDE")
    private Double latitude;

    @Column(name = "LONGITUDE")
    private Double longitude;

    @Column(name = "METROPOLIS_FACTOR")
    private Double metropolisFactor;

    @Convert(converter = YesNoConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "IS_AUTOMATED_DISPATCH")
    private YesNo isAutomatedDispatch;

    @Convert(converter = GeneralStatusConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private GeneralStatus status;

    @Column(name = "PARSIMAP_CITY_CODE")
    private String parsiMapCityCode;

    @Column(name = "AMAR_CITY_CODE")
    private String parsiMapCityAmarCode;

    @JoinColumn(name = "REGIONAL_OFFICE_ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch =  FetchType.LAZY)
    private RegionalOffice regionalOffice;

    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "cities")
    Set<Region> regions = new HashSet<>();

/*    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city")
    private Set<Address> addresses;*/

    public City() {
    }

    public City(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        //   this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    public City(CityDto dto) {
        fromDto(dto);
    }

    public void fromDto(CityDto cityDto) {
        this.name = cityDto.getName();
        this.metropolisFactor = cityDto.getMetropolisFactor();
    }

    public CityDto toDto() {
        CityDto dto = new CityDto();
        dto.setId(id);
        dto.setName(name);
        dto.setMetropolisFactor(metropolisFactor);
        dto.setProvinceDto(province.toDto());
        dto.setRegionalOfficeOutput(regionalOffice.toDto());
        return dto;
    }

    public CityLite toDtoLite() {
        CityLite dto = new CityLite();
        dto.setId(id);
        dto.setName(name);
        dto.setMetropolisFactor(metropolisFactor);
        dto.setProvinceId(province != null ? province.getId() : null);
        dto.setProvinceName(province != null ? province.getName() : "");
        dto.setRegionalOfficeId(regionalOffice != null ? regionalOffice.getId() : null);
        dto.setRegionalOfficeTitle(regionalOffice != null ? regionalOffice.getTitle() : "");
        dto.setParsiMapCityCode(parsiMapCityCode);
        dto.setParsiMapAmarCityCode(parsiMapCityAmarCode);
        dto.setLat(latitude != null ? latitude :0);
        dto.setLng(longitude != null ? longitude :0);
        return dto;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say the following line causes the problem: `. as col_23_0_ `. This indicates reading a 24th column buth the name seems to be a dot. The comma after `Helper0_.MAX_CONCURRENT_WORK as col_22_0_` seems to be correct as there's one more selection item following it.

Comment: you know the thing which should be there is a list I mean `Helper_.DUTY_CITIES`. I think this causes the problem since there is no type list in Oracle so it can't be selected.

Comment: How did you map that list/set in Oracle in the first place? It looks like you have an inner join here which means that you duplicate the rest of the data for each duty city id (cartesian product) which might interfere with "paging" (at least that's how I'd interpret this `where rownum <= ?` portion in the query). Maybe think about loading the duty cities using a separate query.

Comment: the I mapped it with an `@OneToMany` annotation. I don't use any query it is build automatically and I see where the problem was. I used incorrect `mappedBy` attribute.

Comment: So the issue is resolved now? Maybe add an answer detailing what lead to this (include your model if possible) for others to read if they have the same issue.

Comment: alright I will do that

Answer (score 0):

I answered it in a comment in `Helper` entity. the answer is you shouldn't make a mistake in `mappedBy` attribute in `@OneToMany` annotation. so I changed `dutyCityId` to `helper` now it's working.
before it was joining with another condition `helper.ID = helperDutyCity.dutyCityId` which was wrong now it joins with this condition `helper.ID = helperDutyCity.helperId` which is correct.